# When are square brackets required in a Bash if statement?

Tags: bash, if-statement, square-bracket

Usually, I use square brackets in the if statement:

```
if [ "$name" = 'Bob' ]; then ...
```

But, when I check if `grep` succeeded I don't use the square brackets:

```
if grep -q "$text" $file ; then ...
```

When are the square brackets necessary in the `if` statement?

Comment: Single square brackets are compatible across several shells, however a few of them, including Bash, support the preferred double square bracket. See [BashFAQ/031](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) for more information. Also see `help '['`

Answer (score 192, accepted):

The square brackets are a synonym for the `test` command. An `if` statement checks the exit status of a command in order to decide which branch to take. `grep -q "$text"` is a command, but `"$name" = 'Bob'` is not--it's just an expression. `test` is a command, which takes an expression and evaluates it:

```
if test "$name" = 'Bob'; then ...
```

Since square brackets are a synonym for the `test` command, you can then rewrite it as your original statement:

```
if [ "$name" = 'Bob' ]; then ...
```

Comment: @chepner: Why `if $boolean_var ; then ...` doesn't require brackets?

Comment: @misha, if your `$boolean_var` has the value "true" or "false", it works because you're running the **command** `true` or `false`.

Comment: `if $boolean_var ; then ...` does not work if $boolean_var is `0` or `1`, see `man true` and `man false`.

Comment: @derFunk: It would work if you happened to have `0` and `1` commands in your `$PATH` -- but that would be ugly.

Comment: spellcheck doesn't like the brackets, but works with the test statement, in VSCode.

Comment: Then the spellchecker has a problem. `[` is a standard alias for `test`.

Answer (score 47):

`[` is actually a command, equivalent (almost, see below) to the `test` command. It's not part of the shell syntax. (Both `[` and `test`, depending on the shell, are often built-in commands as well, but that doesn't affect their behavior, except perhaps for performance.)

An `if` statement executes a command and executes the `then` part if the command succeeds, or the `else` part (if any) if it fails.  (A command succeeds if it exits with a status (`$?`) of 0, fails if it exits with a non-zero status.)

In

```
if [ "$name" = 'Bob' ]; then ...
```

the command is

```
[ "$name" = 'Bob' ]
```

(You could execute that same command directly, without the `if`.)

In

```
if grep -q "$text" $file ; then ...
```

the command is

```
grep -q "$text" $file
```

`man [` or `man test` for more information.

FOOTNOTE: Well, the `[` command is *almost* equivalent to the `test` command. The difference is that `[` requires `]` as its last argument, and `test` does not -- and in fact doesn't allow it (more precisely, `test` doesn't treat a `]` argument specially; for example it could be a valid file name). (It didn't *have* to be implemented that way, but a `[` without a matching `]` would have made a lot of people very very nervous.)

Comment: spellcheck doesn't like the brackets, but works with the test statement, in VSCode.

Comment: @johnrubythecat: What "spellcheck" are you referring to? If it's something intended to spell check English text, then of course it's not going to be happy about shell syntax.

Comment: plus one for the `nervous` argument.

Comment: I think we are all pretty nervous having lived with shell syntax all these years.  If I saw an omitted closing bracket it would just be "one more thing".

Answer (score 11):

The best way to think of the `[ ... ]` syntax, is to consider `[` to be a program - which it is!

Check this out:

```
~ $ ls /usr/bin/\[ 
/usr/bin/[
```

on the other hand, you're probably not using that version of it since `bash` also provides `[` as a shell built-in.

Anyway, to answer your question: What `if` does is run the command you give it and see it the return value is `0` or not. You use `[` to do other, more interesting comparisons such as string comparisons. See `man [` and `man bash`.

Comment: There's nothing in the bash manpage that indicates that `[` is implemented internally, I think that that's what `[[` is for.

Comment: @PhilHibbs: I'm pretty sure `[` is a built-in. That's why `builtin [` works. `[[` is somewhat different from `[`, it does different things.

Comment: @PhilHibbs: Look under the section SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS of the `bash` man page. `test expr` and `[ expr ]` are listed together.

Comment: @PhilHibbs: Also, try `type -a [`