# Why does Bash treat undefined variables as true in an 'if' statement?

Tags: bash

In the below simple example, if *CONDITION* is not set in the script, running the script prints "True". However, one would expect it to print "False". What is the reason for this behavior?

```
# Set CONDITION by using true or false:
# CONDITION=true or false

if $CONDITION; then
    echo "True"
else
    echo "False"
fi
```

Comment: The Bash has it's own way of checking for an undefined or empty variable .. Your syntax, simply put is thought out wrong.  Bash will look at that statement and say OK  nothing equals nothing ..  So true ..  The way Bash handles checking for empty/non-existent variables is `if [ -z ${CONDITION} ]; then`

Comment: @Zak There's no "equals" here. `if` uses the return code of the condition.

Comment: @wjandrea -- Correct .. But a better way to put it is .. Nothing is something .. so exit 0 .. "true" --  The fact that there are no operators means it will return successful

Comment: More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47876317/5303092

Comment: `$CONDITION` should probably be quoted here. Then you'll get an error message, which I'd consider better behaviour. Also, it should probably be lowercase too, unless it's an environment variable. Then [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) will warn you that it's not assigned.

Comment: [tag:dash] works the same

Comment: Note that what you're doing here is storing a command in `$CONDITION`, and running it when entering the `if`. That's kinda icky in that if some part of the script accidentally stores something unexpected there (or if the value comes from the outside environment!), the script would run that as a command. Best case: an error message, worst case: running a command with consequences. It might be better to explicitly use `[ "$CONDITION" = true ]` to test for `true` vs. any other value (or unset variable); or `[ "$CONDITION" ]` to test for any non-empty value vs. an empty value (or unset variable).

Comment: As a rule of thumb: if a variable isn't quoted there is a 99.9% chance that your script is wrong or broken anyway. There are only very specific circumstances in which non-quoting a variable expansion is what you really want.

Comment: A nice way to do bool variables in bash is to use 0 and 1, and evaluate them with `if ((foo))` arithmetic expansion, which is true for a non-zero numeric result.  [How can I declare and use Boolean variables in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26920580) / [How to perform boolean operations in BASH (outside conditions)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/592967).  Then you don't have to expand a variable as a command name like `/bin/true` or `true`.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The argument to `if` is a statement to execute, and its exit status is tested. If the exit status is `0` the condition is true and the statements in `then` are executed.

When `$CONDITION` isn't set, the statement is an empty statement, and empty statements always have a zero exit status, meaning success. So the `if` condition succeeds.

This behavior is explained in the [POSIX shell specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01):

> If there is no command name, but the command contained a command substitution, the command shall complete with the exit status of the last command substitution performed. Otherwise, the command shall complete with a zero exit status.

Comment: Then why does `if ""; then echo yes; fi` fail on a command not found?

Comment: Because that's not an empty statement. It's trying to find a program whose name is the empty string.

Comment: You'd get the same error if you did `if "$CONDITION"`

Comment: This really is a weird edge case, because `if ; then echo yes; fi` is a syntax error, but `if $unset; then echo yes; fi` is OK. I suppose the difference is that the former is _not_ "given a statement to execute";  the latter is given one but it just happens to be null.

Comment: Right. The difference is that the first error is detected during parsing, while the second executes after the statement is parsed and the variable substituted.

Comment: [2.9.1 Simple Commands](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01), last part: _"If there is no command name, but the command contained a command substitution, the command shall complete with the exit status of the last command substitution performed. Otherwise, the command shall complete with a zero exit status."_ You could also have something like `if "$@"; then ...` which would result in an empty command if there were no positional parameters. The grammar does require at least something there, but a simple redirection would also do...

Comment: @glennjackman FYI ':' can represent the empty command; thus `while :; do ... done` is valid, as is `if :; then...`

Comment: @Dave, but `:` is not an _empty_ command, it's an _actual_ non-empty command. It's a "no op" but it's not actually _no operation_.