# Understand when to use spaces in bash scripts

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I wanted to run a simple bash timer and found this [online](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1559946.html) (user brent7890)

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
timer=60
until [ "$timer" = 0 ]
do
clear
echo "$timer"
timer=`expr $timer - 1`
sleep 1
done
echo "-------Time to go home--------"
```

I couldn't copy and paste this code because the server is on another network.  I typed it like this (below) and got an error on the line that starts with "until".

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
timer=60

#Note I forgot the space between [ and "
until ["$timer" = 0 ]

do
clear
echo "$timer"
timer=`expr $timer - 1`
sleep 1
done
echo "-------Time to go home--------"
```

Where is spacing like this documented?  It seems strange that it matters.  Bash scripts can be confusing, I want to understand why the space is important.

Comment: The confusion behind this question is the primary reason many style guided recommend completely avoiding `[`.  Instead of `until [ "$timer" = 0 ]`, write `until test "$timer" = 0` and the need for spacing becomes obvious.

Comment: In contrast to spaces being required in a `[` (aka `test`) command, they're forbidden in an assignment. `timer=60` works, but `timer = 60` will try to run the `timer` command with the arguments "=" and "60". The lack of spaces is actually how the shell distinguishes an assignment from a regular command. Also, spaces are required around the operators in a `[` command: `[ "$timer"=0 ]` is a valid `test` command, but it doesn't do what you expect because it doesn't recognize `=` as an operator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several rules, two basic of that are these:

- You must separate all arguments of a command with spaces.
- You must separate a command and the argument, that follows after, with a space.

`[` here is a command (`test`).

If you write `["$timer"` that means that you start command `[60`,
and that is, of course, incorrect. The name of the command is `[`.

The name of the command is always separated from the rest of the command line with a space. (you can have a command with a space in it, but in this case you must write the name of the command in `""` or `''`).

Comment: OK, [ is a synonym for the test command.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934012/when-square-brackets-are-required-in-bash-if-statement