# How to check if a function returns true inside an if statement in bash?

Tags: bash, function, if-statement

I want to check if the function mdfind returns true, and by that I mean if it finds what the user specified in a variable from a read call.

This is what I've got but it isn't working:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "Loading..."
sleep 2
clear
echo "Grand Theft Auto Launcher | v1.0"
echo -n "Grand Theft Auto Game Name: "
read game

if [ mdfind $game ]
then
clear
echo "$game found."
echo "Launching..."
fi
```

Comment: debug using `+x` at `#!/bin/bash +x`

Comment: `[` tests values using its predicates. It is a command (not syntax). It **returns** true or false as appropriate. If you want to test a command other then `[`/`test` just use that command directly instead of `[`.

Comment: I don't get it. Could you write an example?

Comment: Just remove `[` and `]` from your example. `if` checks the return code of the command between `if` and `then`. That is very often the `[` command. In your case you want it to be the `mdfind` command.

Comment: See [When square brackets are required in bash if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934012/when-square-brackets-are-required-in-bash-if-statement)

Comment: Thanks, it worked! :)