# How does -d work in if statements when checking for return codes?

Tags: bash, shell

I can across some code in a bash script that has confused me a little.

The code checks to see if the directory/file exists. If the return code is 0 ... success, otherwise the file doesn't exist:

```
if [ -d /usr/local/bin ]
then
    echo "Exists"
else
    echo "Does not exist"
fi
```

What program is `-d /usr/local/bin` using to check if the file exists? The other example in the book is:

```
test -d /usr/local/bin

if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Exists"
else
    echo "Does not exist"
fi
```

Which leads me to believe the first example us using `test` within the `if`. And if so, why does this happen automatically without having to specify the `test` program?

Comment: square brackets are a synonym for `test` http://stackoverflow.com/a/8934070/12016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square brackets are *not* part of the shell grammar.  Rather `[` is a command with the very odd feature of requiring its last argument to be the literal string `]`.  The command you are executing is `[` with the 4 arguments `N`, `-eq`, `0`, and `]` where `N` is the value that the shell variable `?` currently expands to (likely either `0` or `1`).  In the past, `/bin/[` was often literally a link to the same file as `/bin/test`, and that executable behaved slightly differently when it was invoked through that link (it checked that the last argument was `]`).  Other than the check on the last argument, `[` is exactly the same as the command `test`.

It might be clearer if the second example did not explicitly check `$?` but had instead simply been written:

```
if test -d /usr/local/bin
then
    echo "Exists"
else
    echo "Does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: Very interesting to know. I just did `file /bin/[` and it shows as an executable. `man [` is the same man page for `test` which confirms your answer. Thanks for the detailed explanation. The book I'm reading is "Mastering Unix Shell Scripting". The last example your provided is also listed :)