# Why does if $var work, but if [[ $var1 || $var2 ]] does not?

Tags: bash

Why does it work if I test a single variable if it's `true`, but it doesn't work if I check 2 variables if either is `true`? Am I overlooking something super obvious and simple here?

Why does below code work:

```
var1=false
var2=false

if "$var1"; then
  echo "true"
else
  echo "false"
fi
```

but this doesn't:

```
var1=false
var2=false

if [[ "$var1" || "$var2" ]]; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false: "
fi
```

as it always returns `true`

Comment: Try `if [[ "$var1" == true || "$var2" == true ]]; then`.

Comment: The equivalent for two variables is `if "$var1" || "$var2"`, no `[[ ... ]]` involved.

Comment: Also see [When are square brackets required in a Bash if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8934012/4154375).

Comment: `if false` returns the program named `false`, which sets exit code 1. `if [[ false ]]` tests whether the string between the brackets is not empty, and if this is the case (and it is, because the word _false_ consists of 5 characters), sets exit code 0. In simpler words: You have program execution in the first case, and string test in the second. You can't expect the same result ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I you have

```bash
var=true
if "$var"; then
```

you're actually running

```bash
if true; then
```

The variable expands, and the `true` command is executed.

If you do

```bash
var1=false
if [[ $var ]]; then
```

you're running a shortcut for

```bash
if [[ -n $var ]]
```

which is true if `$var` is not empty.

So, this

```bash
[[ $var1 || $var2 ]]
```

is true if any of `$var1` or `$var2` are not empty, no matter what they contain.

To check if any of them has the value `true`, don't use `[[ ... ]]` at all:

```bash
if "$var1" || "$var2"
```

Notice that Bash doesn't have the concept of booleans. `true` and `false` are just strings, and `if "$var1"` behaves the way it does because there is a *command* called `true` (and also one for `false`).

Comment: When `var1=date`, you will be executing something you don't want.

Comment: @WalterA I think it's generally not a good idea to rely on the exit status of commands stored in variables. I suspect people use this because `if true` and `if false` look like more conventionally used boolean logic, but for Bash, there are likely better approaches.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison isn't doing whatever it is you think it's doing, and the two statements are entirely dissimilar. Because of the way Bash parses such things:

```bash
set -x

var1="false"
if "$var1"; then
    echo "This branch never executes."
fi

var1="true"
if "$var1"; then echo $?; fi
set +x
```

shows that this minor adaptation of your code is actually *running* the `true` or `false` binary in your *PATH* (probably `/bin/false` or `/bin/true` in most cases) and returning the exit status from the binary. Likewise, `[[ "true" ]]` and `[[ "false" ]]` always exit zero because this construct creates in implicit `-n` test (e.g. variable exists and is not empty), so you aren't doing any comparisons where there's a failing condition since both *var1* and *var2* are defined.

What you probably want is string equality. For example:

```bash
set -x

var1="false"
var2="true"

if [[ "$var1" = "true" ]] || [[ "$var2" = "true" ]]
then
  echo "At least one of the two values is true."
fi

set +x
```

This performs a *string* comparison between the values, and returns an appropriate exit status with a Boolean short-circuit.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that they are testing different things.

```
if [[ "$VAR1" ]]
then 
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false" 
fi
```

And anything else within a `[[ ]]` tests if the variable has more than 0 characters. This is like `[[ -n "$VAR1" ]]`. So a variable like `VAR3=""` would return `false`.  But checking:

```
if "$VAR1"
then 
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false" 
fi
```

Test the content of the variable. If you will run the 1st check with an undefined variable (say, `$VAR3`, in this case) it would return false, whereas doing the same with the 2nd test would simply return an error.

Comment: `[[ "$VAR1" ]]` doesn't test that a variable exists, it's equivalent to `[[ -n "$VAR1" ]]` which tests that the length of the string is non-zero. `if "$VAR1"` is running the contents of the variable as a command and branching based on its exit status.

Comment: Yes, exactly. A variable existing would be tested with e.g. `[[ -v VAR1 ]]` (note no dollar sign) or with some parameter expansion trick like `[ "${VAR1+x}" = "x" ]` in older shells that don't support the bash-specific extended test.

Comment: @tjm3772, corrected the answer. Thanks!